# JQuery resizable: grid + aspectRatio not resizing correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When using the JQuery resizable method with aspect ratio and grid, the resizing happens at different times for the X and Y axis. This can cause the aspect ratio to change over time.

```
aspectRatio: true,
grid: [50, 50]
```

See this JSFiddle for an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gpvhduf3/

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your resizable element is having different width and height, while aspectRatio is true,  grid values must be in the same ratio as the height and width, so for 250px * 150px div it should be grid: [50, 30]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#box').resizable({
   handles: 'nw, ne, sw, se, n, s, e, w',
   aspectRatio: true,
    grid: [50, 30]
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div id="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can provide an aspect ratio rather than true.

like aspectRatio: 16 / 9

```
$( "#resizable" ).resizable({
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9
    });
```

or

Refer: http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#aspect-ratio